# jQuery .blur() - Don't hide active div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, blur

Why does this code hide the div that's used as the jQuery selector on blur() if I click inside it? Blur() should only hide it if I click outside it.

**HTML trigger:**

```
<div class="header">To-Do <a class="triggernewtodo">Add a task...</a></div>
```

**li to show/hide:**

```
<li class="addnewtodo">
<form>
    <textarea class="addtodotextarea"></textarea>
    <div class="controlarea">
    <input class="primary" name="commit" type="submit" value="Add" />
    </div>
</form>
</li>
```

**jQuery:**

```
// Show/Hide New Todo form
$('a.triggernewtodo').click(function() {
    $('li.addnewtodo').show()
    $('textarea.addtodotextarea').focus();
});

$('li.addnewtodo').live("blur", function() {
    $(this).hide();
})
```

My guess is that it has something to do with the .focus() placed on the textarea, because if I take out that .focus(), it works properly until I click inside the textarea then click out (still inside the list item) and it hides the whole list item. Any ideas? What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Why are you using `$.live`? It's deprecated. Also, please don't post the server side language code, paste the generated HTML

Comment: When the question does not pertain to your back-end code, it is always better to include your rendered html in your question rather than the code which creates it.

Comment: I can guess your text area is inside the li element. When giving focus to that element, your li element executes the blur function. Thus, hiding it. You can check to see if the textarea element has focus before hiding it

Comment: All right sorry guys, I edited it to show the generated html instead of the server side code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect you're seeing an event that's "bubbled up" from within that LI.  Essentially, a "blur" event from the INPUT, say, triggers all the "blur" handlers on that input.  *Then* it triggers all the "blur" handlers on the FORM.  Then it triggers the "blur" handlers on the LI - hiding it.

The event continues all the way up the DOM tree unless you call [stopPropagation](http://api.jquery.com/event.stopPropagation/) to prevent this.  In your case, you should be able to use the [event.target](http://api.jquery.com/event.target/) property to see if the event actually originated at the LI, and only hide it in that situation (warning: untested):

```
$('li.addnewtodo').live("blur", function(event) {
    if(event.target == this)
    {
        $(this).hide();
    }
});
```

Hope that helps!

**PS:** See the page on the [blur event](http://api.jquery.com/blur/) for additional caveats.